# in ipython how do I accept and use an autocomplete suggestion?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm using Python 3.8.9 with IPython 8.0.1 on macOS. When I type anything whatsoever, it displays a predicted suggestion based on past commands. Cool.

However, how do I actually accept that suggestion? I tried the obvious: tab, which does *not* accept the suggestion, but rather opens up a menu with *different* suggestions, while the original suggestion is still there (see screenshot).

I also tried space, and return, but both of those act as if the suggestion was never made. How the heck do I actually *use* the ipython autosuggestion? Or is tab supposed to work and something is wrong with my ipython build or something?

[image]

Comment: Use down arrow to scroll through the list, and hit return on the highlight choice.  Here's it's just suggesting that you could use `%load bar.py` or `%loacpy ...` etc.  If all you want is the `load`, just space or right arrow to move on.

Comment: space does *not* work. If I hit space, I just get `%load ` and the `bar.py` part disappears. Right arrow does work though, as I say in my answer

Comment: I guess scrolling right on to the suggestion is so second-nature to me that I couldn't picture what was your problem.  So you got the suggestion, but tab pulled up the menu.  Scrolling right should both get rid of the menu, and move you accepting the filename suggestion.  End-of-line  might also work.  Come to think of it, I just get suggestions with tab.  I don't have full auto-complete enabled.

Comment: the problem was that usually completion is done using tab. For example, in bash if I do `cd; cd Doc<TAB>` it completes with `Documents`. In ipython, TAB does *not* do this, I have to press "right arrow key" which I've never had to do in any other shell / REPL-like program before, and I've used a *lot* of them

Comment: In `bash`, `tab` completes it as long as its unambiguous, then it displays possibilities, and  creates a new line.  `ipython` tab creates a drop down menu

Comment: I just upgraded `ipython` and started getting this autocomplete.  For a second I was puzzled by the flash of code.  So yes, you either have to use right arrow to accept the suggestion, or something else to overwrite it.  Up also accepts, and down rejects it.  If I don't get used to it, I may have to look for a way to turn it off.  I suppose I could also do the right thing and look up the documentation.  It's probably provided by some extra package.

Comment: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version8.html#autosuggestons - release notes for v8 documents this `autosuggestions` feature.

Comment: note in the screenshot of this question that the dropdown menu doesn't actually include the `bar.py` that is displayed in grey. That means there are actually two *different* sets of suggestions here, and thus the dropdown menu is *not* what I want

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`CTRL-E`, `CTRL-F`, or `Right Arrow Key`
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/8.13.2/config/shortcuts/index.html

Comment: None of these work in a VSCode terminal.  Solution: the `End` key

Answer (score 23):

pressing the right arrow key on my keyboard was the only thing that worked. Kind of non-obvious.

Answer (score 8):

Use any key that moves your cursor to the right e.g. <kbd>END</kbd>, <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd>, or <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd>.

Note that <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> are simply Emacs' keys for moving cursor to the right and to the end of the line respectively.

Comment: Funny, with the newest version 8.13.2 right arrow isn't working anymore for autocompletion. In a previous version it didn't work at all. Now the fixed it, but they didn't fix it for autocompletion too. A rather annoying regression.

Comment: Up Arrow worked for me on macos

Comment: @Lethargos, this seems fixed in version 8.14. Right arrow works again.