# IPython command completion with up arrow

Tags: ipython

I recently upgraded IPython and the up arrow behaviour changed. Previously, I could get the entire command from my history. Now, it's greyed out and I have to press right to complete it before I can press enter or edit it:

[image: IPython screenshot]

When did this change? How do I get the previous behaviour back?

Comment: This may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102876/in-ipython-how-do-i-accept-and-use-an-autocomplete-suggestion

Comment: Apparently ctrl+up cycles through previous commands now. Don't know how to change the behaviour fully, though