# How to "accept" the single (non-dropdown) ipython auto-completion

Tags: ipython

`ipython` got it right here: I would like to "accept" the auto-completion:

[image]

Which keystroke allows me to accept it? I have tried right arrow, down-arrow, tab, space and various and sundry other keystrokes, none have done the magic.

Note: there is a very similar question but it applies to the *drop-down* list:  [in ipython how do I accept and use an autocomplete suggestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102876/in-ipython-how-do-i-accept-and-use-an-autocomplete-suggestion)

Comment: from ipython docs `If there is only a single option, pressing the Tab key will complete the line for you.`

Comment: Well then why does that not work?

Comment: Try `End` key to go to the end of the line, and then enter

Comment: @hpaulj that _does_ work . feel free to make answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment by @hpaulj:

> Try End key to go to the end of the line, and then enter

This works.